# How do I set up "userid" equivalent view from Google Analytics in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, firebase

I am trying to use firebase analytics in my iOS app. I have been using Google analytics (GA) before. in GA, just to make sure that I get true user count (i.e. a user who had the app, uninstalls the app and then reinstalls the app, should still be treated as only 1 user), I was using userid view in GA which works well for me.

Per [How does Firebase Analytics define a "user" (for purposes of Audience)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517060/how-does-firebase-analytics-define-a-user-for-purposes-of-audience), it seems firebase doesn't have  such mechanism. So how do I capture this stats in firebase analytics? I could have updated the same question but I still don't have comment access in stack overflow yet.

Thanks,
Abhijit

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FirebaseAnalytics.setUserId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#public-methods) to set your user IDs. You can then link the account to BigQuery and count distinct users using BigQuery. BigQuery has free tier that should be sufficient for most app.

Comment: Will try that. Thanks for the suggestion.