# Firebase - building Audiences based on Event Parameters

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I'm having a hard time configuring my audiences in the Firebase console based on the custom event parameters I'm passing in my custom "test_event".

Below is the structure of a "test_event" as seen in Google BigQuery JSON table -

```
{
    "name": "test_event",
    "params": [
      {
        "key": "aoi_name",
        "value": {
          "string_value": "update_button",
          "int_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "double_value": null
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "firebase_event_origin",
        "value": {
          "string_value": "app",
          "int_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "double_value": null
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "screen_name",
        "value": {
          "string_value": "main_activity",
          "int_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "double_value": null
        }
      } ]
```

What I want to observe is an audience clicking on "update_button" on the "main_activity" screen. Based on events of similar kind, I want to create Funnels for observing my user flows.

The problem is whenever I create an Audience -

[image]

It shows me no activity and number of users is always 0. Is this not the correct way to achieve the funnels I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup looks good, it might help to post the code used to log the events as well. However, I think the issue might just be that audiences only start to accumulate from the point you create the audience onward ([docs](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en)):

> Once created, an audience accumulates users who meet the specified criteria from that point onward.

In addition, what may also cause you to think tracking is not working, is that the audience user count is only shown when once it exceeds 10 users (for privacy reasons):

> Number of users in this audience that triggered events.
>   Due to privacy restrictions, we do not show data for an audience with fewer than 10 users.

(taken from the help dialog when hovering over the little question mark when viewing audiences)

[image]

Comment: Hi @Adam. Yes I figured this out yesterday and got a "debug" version of the app installed on 13 different devices (users). The problem still remains the same. Now when I'm trying to make a new Audience, the User count on the same console page shows < 10 users. Is it that the audience can be made only on "Active" users? Because it can be that those users have uninstalled the debug app today.

Comment: It could also be your audience definition is not being met so you should double check that. Perhaps try creating a very simple audience definition (eg. based on a user property) and then test to make sure that works first. Also, with regards to testing, you can just uninstall/install your app to create a new unique user - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37529141/268156