# Firebase remote config with audience does not work

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-remote-config

Below are the steps i'm following to create a custom audience based remote config condition -

1. First I created a user property called OEM

[image: User property]

2. I created a dynamic link with `utm_source` as `google-micromax`

   https://d83j2.app.goo.gl/?link=http://myapp.in&apn=com.myapp.app&utm_source=google-micromax&utm_medium=micromax_device&utm_campaign=promo_google_micromax
3. I created an `OEM-Micromax` audience with the condition that the user property `OEM` contains `google-micromax`

[image: Audience]

4. I then created a remote config condition based on the Micromax audience

[image: remote config]

5. I then handle the dynamic link and set the user property to the value returned from the link's `utm_source`

   ```
   AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, this, autoLaunchDeepLink)
   .setResultCallback(
   new ResultCallback<AppInviteInvitationResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onResult(AppInviteInvitationResult result) {
       if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
         //First time user
         if (StorageHelper.getBooleanObject(StorageHelper.FIRST_TIME_USER, true)) {

           Intent intent = result.getInvitationIntent();
           String deepLink = AppInviteReferral.getDeepLink(intent);
           Uri uri = Uri.parse(deepLink);
           String utm_source = uri.getQueryParameter("utm_source");
           FirebaseEvents.setUserProperty(utm_source);

           StorageHelper.setBooleanObject(StorageHelper.FIRST_TIME_USER, false);
         }
         FirebaseEvents.logEventInvite(true);
       }
     }
   });
   ```
6. Now, when I fetch the `oem_admob_banner_unit_id` parameter from remote config, it still returns the **Default** value instead of the value for the Micromax audience.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is related to your issue, but I also could not get an audience-driven remote config to work. (Mine happened to be an audience based on an app event/parameter so it's a little different scenario but maybe similar problem). It finally started working after I forced enough users in the audience by triggering my event repeatedly. Not sure how many it was, probably around 10.

Comment: Hey Allen, Thanks for your response. Did you have to add users into the audience from 10 different devices or did you do that from a single device?

Comment: I used 1 device to do this. I did this on both iOS and Android apps (install, trigger event, uninstall, repeat). I did this based on this SO answer and it seems to be accurate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37529141/1973199

Answer (score 0):

after fetching, you should call

```
FIRRemoteConfig - (BOOL)activateFetched
```

> Applies Fetched Config data to the Active Config, causing updates to the behavior and appearance
>   of the app to take effect (depending on how config data is used in the app).
>
> Returns true if there was a Fetched Config, and it was activated.
>
> Returns false if no Fetched Config was found, or the Fetched Config was already activated.