# How can I get the MAU per tenant in Firebase Auth / Google Identity Platform?

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics, google-identity

I see that the Firebase console only shows MAU at the project level with various filters. I didn't see a filter per tenant.

When I enable multi-tenancy in Firebase Auth/Identity Platform, is there a way to find out the MAU count per tenant?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Analytics data is not linked to Firebase Authentication in any way.  If you're seeing MAU in Analytics, it is not measuring Firebase Auth users.  [It is measuring its own sense of "user"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517060/how-does-firebase-analytics-define-a-user-for-purposes-of-audience), based on the tokens it uses independently from Firebase Auth.

If you want per-tenant stats, you should add tenant information as user properties in custom events, export Analytics data to BigQuery, then gain insights from your data using BigQuery queries.  The console won't be of help when working with user properties like this.